# QT Wrong JPEG Library version

Tags: c++, qt, opensuse

I'm trying to build and run an application with Qt Creator, but got the error message `Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80`. I've already remove the old version of my library on my OpenSuse system and installed the new `libjpeg8`. But still get the same error. 
I was trying the same with YaST installer on OpenSuse, but it isn't help me too.

One more thing. When I try to build and run an application with the same code (from examples, it is camera example). It doesnt request it and start without problems. When I commentout the code from the camera example in my application, its starts.

I've already search and read the other Questions here on stackoverflow.